# Show $2$-degenerate graphs are subgraphs of $2$-degenerate plane bipartite graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

I am trying to prove or find a counterexample for the following claim: any planar $2$-degenerate graph is a subgraph of a $2$-degenerate plane bipartite graph (a planar graph whose faces are all $4$-gons). It is known that $2$-degenerate bipartite graphs can be obtained from $C_4$ by inserting a vertex of degree 2 (and thus two new edges at the same time). My idea was to argue that one could take any $2$-degenerate planar graph and add edges and vertices in such manner to obtain a plane bipartite graph, but I am completely lacking the argument of how to make sure that 1) this is in fact always possible, and 2) the resulting plane graph is in fact bipartite and 2-degenerate.

$2$-degenerate graphs are graphs such that every subgraph of a $2$-degenerate graph contains a vertex of degree $2$.

Comment: Maybe you could type in a definition of *2-degenerate*?

Comment: Is a triangle $K_3$ not a counter-example?

Comment: Thanks for typing in the definition – but I'm having trouble making any sense out of it. Every graph has the empty graph as a subgraph, and the empty graph has no vertex of degree two, so it appears there's no such thing as a $2$-degenerate graph. If you don't like the empty graph, then just take a subgraph with only one vertex, or only two vertices; those subgraphs also have no vertex of degree two. Is there something missing in the definition? Some requirement on the admissible subgraphs?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Usually the definition of $2$-degenerate asks for every subgraph (excluding the null graph) to have a vertex of degree **at most** $2$.

Comment: try to use the Split-Off Lemma

Comment: @Botanicus If you are giving hints, does that mean you see a way that the existence of graphs like $K_3$ does not ruin the statement?